# Vue 3 click event does not trigger on anything

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Trying to use vue 3, got some things working like using a v-for.
But the @click just doesn't trigger anything. So I tried using the demo from the vue documention https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#listening-to-events

My code:

```
<template>
<nav id="menu">
    <button @click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
    <p>The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times.</p>

    <ul class="menu-main" @click="console.log('do something')">
        <template v-for="item in items">
            <li @click="alert('test')">
                {{item.name}}
                <ul class="menu-sub" v-show="currentItem == item.key">
                    <li v-for="subItem in item.children" :key="subItem.key">
                        {{subItem.name}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
        </template>
    </ul>
</nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'menu-component',
    data() {
        return {
            counter: 0,
            currentItem: null,
            items: [
                {
                    key: 1,
                    name: "Main Item A",
                    children: [
                        {
                            key: 2,
                            name: "Sub Item A-A"
                        },
                        {
                            key: 3,
                            name: "Sub Item A-B"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    key: 4,
                    name: "Main Item B",
                    children: [
                        {
                            key: 5,
                            name: "Sub Item B-A"
                        },
                        {
                            key: 6,
                            name: "Sub Item B-B"
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        };
    },
    methods: {
        changeCurrentItem(item) {
            console.log("Hello, do something", item);
        }
    }
};
```

But both the demo button @click event and the @click in the ul or li don't trigger anything.

I have the feeling that I am missing something.

Comment: I made a mistake somewhere else that causes everything else after to fail. Sorry for wasting every ones time.

Answer (score 2):

This is because template variables are scoped to the current component.

```html
@click="console.log('do something')"
```

is like calling

```js
this.console.log('do something');
```

within your component script, which fails because `this.console` doesn't exist within the component scope.

Instead, define methods on your component and call those via the click event.

```
methods: {
    doSomething() {
        console.log("do something");
    }
}
```

```html
@click="doSomething"
```

Comment: I made a mistake somewhere else that causes everything else after to fail. Sorry for wasting every ones time.